# installation of ubuntu with windows7

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I am having configuration AMD Sempron145 prosessor, with 2GB RAM and 512MB graphics. Already having win7 ultimate 32bit and want to use ubuntu 32bit with windows7 as dual boot!

How to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Go to the below website
More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

You might not know that your Sempron 145 processor has a hidden second
core that can be unlocked turning it into an Athlon II x2 Dual Core if 
your motherboard has that feature. You should Google it to learn more.